# EJB3 and EntityManagerMap at Runtime

Tags: java, jboss, ejb, entitymanager

I need to make an EJB3 stateful which creates a map of EntityManager.
I want use it to manage multy database dynamically created at runtime.
I define one default persistence unit in the persistence.xml deployment descriptor.

my persistance.xml:

(I used Jboss5 and I defined a datasource)

```
   <persistence-unit name="mkyong">
      <jta-data-source>java:/mkyong_jtds</jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql " value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
            <property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>

        </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
```

I need to create 10 EntityManager, 
each one differs only from connection ulr and I need to define specified values at runtime.
I want create their from an administrative user interface.

something like:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="mkyong")
private EntityManager manager;

Map<String, EntityManager> entityManagerMap = new HashMap<String, EntityManager>();

entityManagerMap.put("mkyong", manager);

Map<String, Object> configOverrides = new HashMap<String, Object>();
configOverrides.put("hibernate.connection.url", "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433/Anagrafe");
EntityManagerFactory programmaticEmf =
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("mkyong", configOverrides);
manager1=programmaticEmf.createEntityManager();
entityManagerMap.put("Anagrafe", manager1);
```

In this sample I created 2  EntityManager

One real EntityManager created automatically named 'mkyong'.

One EntityManager created at runtime named 'Anagrafe'.

...

If I use the real EntityManager work fine... it create table...it persist..

but if i try to use the new one... dont'work... it dont create table and dont store values

Why?

NO ERROR... NO LOG... simply dont write on DB and dont create tables

---

PS: If I config two persistence-unit inside persistance.xml and I use two injected entity manager work fine.

Comment: If all you say is "it don't work", noone's going to help you. What happens when you try? An exception?  If so, show us the exception.

Comment: I edited the question whit more detail... the first problem was TransactionManager ... an I add this line<property name="hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class" value="org.hibernate.transaction.JBossTransactionManagerLookup"/>